# Downloading/Installing Visual Studio 2019 with Powershell

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I have this code. It is supposed to download visual studio via a powershell script

```
$url = "https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=professional&rel=16&utm_medium=microsoft&utm_source=learn.microsoft.com&utm_campaign=link+cta&utm_content=download+commandline+parameters+vs2019"
New-Item -Path 'C:\dev\pub\vs' -ItemType Directory -force

$downloadPath = "C:\dev\pub\vs"
$filePath = "C:\dev\pub\vs\vs_professional.exe"
#Invoke-WebRequest -URI $url -OutFile $filePath

$workloadArgument = @(
   
    '--add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.SDK'

    '--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17134'

    '--add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.TargetingPack'
) 

$optionsAddLayout          = [string]::Join(" ", $workloadArgument )
$optionsQuiet              = "--quiet"
$optionsLayout             = "--layout $downloadPath"
$optionsIncludeRecommended = "--includeRecommended"

$vsOptions = @(
    $optionsLayout,
    $optionsIncludeRecommended,
    $optionsAddLayout
    $optionsQuiet
)

Start-Process -FilePath $filePath -ArgumentList $vsOptions
```

For some reason, Invoke-WebRequest isn't downloading the file it is supposed to be. If you go to the link, a file gets automatically downloaded (the correct file), but the cmdlet gives the wrong file. I was wondering how I can get this to download the correct .exe so I can use Start-Process.

Thanks.

Comment: For me, it downloads an online installer which shall connect to VS server for downloading and installing the setup. What file does it result in for you? Are you expecting an offline installer?

Comment: I get a 200kb .exe file which when I try to run it, it says that my OS (windows) doesn't support files of that type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that it's not a direct link to the "actual" installer. When you go to the "Download" page that you mentioned:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=professional&rel=16&utm_medium=microsoft&utm_source=learn.microsoft.com&utm_campaign=link+cta&utm_content=download+commandline+parameters+vs2019

The code displays the page, then the page kicks off a piece of javascript that makes the actual request to the "real" link (i.e. the website doesn't change, and all real links are all stored in a database somewhere).

To get the "real" link, start your web browser, open up the Developer Tools (`F12`). Go to the "Network" tab. Go to the "download" page that you have above. Wait till you get the download request. In the Network traffic, you should see one request for the `vs_Professional.exe` page. Then you can copy the link address to the direct download:

[image: Getting the link]

This gets you the direct link, which (caution) may change/break with different versions and releases, so you might have to get the new link a couple of times. The link I got for right now is:

https://download.visualstudio.microsoft.com/download/pr/e730a0bd-baf1-4f4c-9341-ca5a9caf0f9f/4358b712148b3781631ab8d0eea42af736398c8b44fba868b76cb255b3de7e7c/vs_Professional.exe

Comment: Do you know how to use powerShell to automate replacing the link in my script? I'm guessing that Copy as PowerShell might have something to do with it, but will updates break that as well?

Comment: The installers can also be found on aka.ms with a predictable pattern of `https://aka.ms/vs/{major}/release/vs_{edition}` where `{major}` is the release number, e.g., `17` for VS 2022, and `edition` maps to community, professional, or enterprise. For example, Visual Studio Professional 2022 is at https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_professional.exe